# how to pass the functions with args in an inline function in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, arguments, inline

```
function emotions(myString, myFunc) {
    console.log("I am " + myString + ", " + myFunc(2));
}

// your code goes here
// call the emotions function here and pass in an
 var laugh = function(max){
    var str ="";
    for(var i=0; i<max ;i++){
        str += "ha";
    }
    return str+"!";
};

// inline function expression
emotions("happy", laugh(2));
```

can anyone revert me , where I made a mistake? Thanks to all in advance

Comment: Just use `emotions("happy", laugh);`? Why do you need to use an argument at that point?

Comment: yeah , it makes me a sense , thanks for info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emotions function accepts 2 arguments- 
 1. myString - which is a string
 2. myFunc - which is a function

The laugh function returns a string. 
laugh(2) =>  haha!

Hence, you should just pass laugh as a parameter to emotions as follows 
  emotions("happy", laugh)